# Transform is not applied on Embedded SVGs Chrome

Tags: html, svg

I am new to using SVGs, but everything was fine until I tried my code on chrome and found that it doesn't work properly, all transform attributes are neglected. Firefox gets it done as expected.

My problem is that the transform attribute is not working when I assign it to embedded SVG (SVG inside an SVG). This problem doesn't occur in Firefox.

Here is a sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      viewBox="0 0 300 100"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      stroke="red"
      fill="grey"
    >
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
      <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="4" />

      <svg transform="translate(0,50)" viewBox="0 0 10 10" x="200" width="100">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will notice that the circle with the thick red border moves a little bit downward when this code runs in Firefox, but it stays in its place when the code runs in chrome.

Why does this happen and how to solve it?

Thank you so much! <3

Comment: Try removing the commas inside your translate. SVG has a slightly different syntax from CSS when it comes to the transform attribute. They both work, so I would say that it’s stupid but tis what itis.

Comment: @somethinghere
Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate your help, but the problem still exists. It works on firefox only. :(

Comment: The answer below explains the situation. You are trying somerhing very novel, so support just isn’t there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform` attributes on `<svg>` elements are a feature added with the SVG 2 spec. Its implementation is still a bit uneven.

Just set the attribute `y="50"` to achieve the same effect, or, if for some reason you are not able to do so, wrap the `<svg>` element in a `<g>` and apply the transform there.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. You helped me a lot! 

Thank you so much! <3

Wish you the best