# Set transform and size of <use> to allow it to be saved as .svg files correctly for editing

Tags: css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I created an `<svg>` element with JavaScript, here are my codes:

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg id="stroke_carrot" fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="0px" height="0px">
 
        <path d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
                                    9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
                                    2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
                                    2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8">
        </path>
                                  
    </svg>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="myPat" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="88" height="88" patternTransform="translate(0,0) rotate(0)">
        <use width="44" height="44" xlink:href="#stroke_carrot"  style="transform: translate3d(40px, 0px, 0px) rotate(80deg);"></use>
        <use width="44" height="44" xlink:href="#stroke_carrot" style="transform: translate3d(60px, 0px, 0px) rotate(50deg);"></use>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="url(#myPat)"> </rect>

</svg>
```

The `<svg>` looks like this on the webpage, you can run the codes to see it.

[image: SVG on the webpate]

Then I save this `<svg>` element as `.svg` file, and open it in Adobe Illustrator to edit it. It becomes different, like this:

[image: SVG in Adobe Illustrator]

Apparently, the `transform` attributes (position and rotation) do not work. Do you know how to make the transform work?
I want to save the `<svg>` element to a same looking `.svg` file that I can edit in Adobe Illustrator.

I tried to use `x=` and `y=` to set the position in the codes, then it works in the Illustrator. For the rotation I don't find a way to do. Also, since the other features of my site are not compatible with `x` and `y` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034206/how-to-make-svg-use-element-rotate-around-its-own-center)), so I still hope I could be able to use `transform` to achieve it.

Comment: that's not a transform attribute, it's a transform style. If you stick to [transform attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) you'll have much more success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `transform` attributes directly to `<use>` elements.

Besides, nested svgs usually cause a lot of troubles for vector graphic applications – so be careful!

#### Example – tested in AI cs6 (so quite old..) and inkscape

```html
<svg width="300px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
        <path id="stroke_carrot" 
        d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
        9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
        2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
        2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8">
        </path>
    <pattern id="myPat" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="88" height="88" >
        <use fill="orange" href="#stroke_carrot" xlink:href="#stroke_carrot" transform="rotate(80 45 25) translate(20 0)" />
        <use fill="blue" href="#stroke_carrot" xlink:href="#stroke_carrot" transform="rotate(50 65 25) translate(40 0)" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="url(#myPat)"> </rect>
</svg>
```

#### Some common practices for standalone or editable svgs

- include **namespace attributes** like `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`   `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` for best compatibility – **well done!**
- include **legacy href syntax** `xlink:href` for `<use>` references. Although these are classified as deprecated – they are still needed by a lot of apps. You can also add the recommended `href`.– also well done!
- use more **"conservative" styling/formatting** methods and features:
  A lot of applications only support a reduced set of svg features (or vaguely described as svg 1.0-1.1 compatibility – not by any means precise)
- transformations: As recommended by @Robert Longson: svg transform **attributes tend to be more reliable**:
  3d transformations like `translate3d` might not be interpreted correctly.
  Related properties like `transform-origin` or `transform-box` for specifying e.g. a pivot point for a rotation might also be ignored by some apps.
  A workaround can be to convert all transformations to a [**matrix**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73573440/transform-origin-css-property-not-recognized-by-illustrator/73601928#73601928).
- **avoid nested svgs** – a lot of applications will struggle to calculate these nested viewBoxes or x/y offsets.
  In your case you can easily define your carrot path within the `<defs>` (or create a `<symbol>`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer of @herrstrietzel, I updated a version with `<symbol>`. In this way we can resize the `<use>` element.

```html
<svg width="300px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="carrot" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <path d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8z" />
  </symbol>
  
  <pattern id="myPat" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="88" height="88" >
    <use xlink:href="#carrot" width="30" height="30" fill="orange" transform="rotate(80 45 25) translate(20 0)"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#carrot" width="60" height="60" fill="blue" transform="rotate(50 65 25) translate(40 0)"></use>
  </pattern>
  
  <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="url(#myPat)"> </rect>
</svg>
```

---- original answer ----

It does not work to set transform attribute/style for the `<use>` element directly, but we can embedded the `<use>` in the `<svg>` and `<g>`.
In this way we can also resize and recolor the referenced element (the `<path>` in this case).

Now it can be displayed properly in the browser, as well as be saved as an `.svg` file and opened for editing in Adobe Illustrator

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
    <svg fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="0px" height="0px">
        <path  id="stroke_carrot" d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
                                    9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
                                    2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
                                    2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8">
        </path>
    </svg>

    <defs>
        <pattern id="myPat" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="88" height="88"  patternTransform="translate(0,0) rotate(0)">
            <g transform = "rotate(80 45 25) translate(20 0)">
                <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50"  fill="orange">
                    <use xlink:href="#stroke_carrot"></use>
                </svg>
            </g>
            
            <g transform = "rotate(50 65 25) translate(40 0)">
                <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50"  fill="blue">
                    <use xlink:href="#stroke_carrot"></use>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  
    <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="url(#myPat)"> </rect>
</svg>
```

Note:

1. We need to wrap the `<svg>` in `<g>`, and set `transform` for `<g>`, to make it work for Chrome. More details see:  [Transform is not applied on Embedded SVGs Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514861/transform-is-not-applied-on-embedded-svgs-chrome)
2. [Rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform): The `rotate(<a> [<x> <y>])` transform function specifies a rotation by a degrees about a given point.
3. Since I want the carrot rotates around its own center, I set the parameters for the `transform` attribute like this:`transform = "rotate(degree width/2+x height/2+y) translate(x y)"`